# Tensor Contraction Speed Up (Matrix Product States)

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, tensors

I'm recently trying to implement some tensor contractions in Mathematica for use in Matrix Product State algorithms.

Here's the operation I want to perform

$$
M^{\sigma_{i}\sigma_{i}'[i]}_{(b_{i-1},a_{i-1}),(b_{i},a_{i})} = \sum_{\sigma_{i}''}T^{\sigma_{i}\sigma_{i}''[i]}_{b_{i-1}b_{i}}W^{\sigma_{i}''\sigma_{i}'[i]}_{a_{i-1}a_{i}}
$$

Here is what I have coded that correctly produces what I want,

```
n = 10;

W = RandomComplex[1 + I, {n, 2, 2, 64, 64}];

W[[1]] = RandomComplex[1 + I, {2, 2, 1, 4}];
W[[2]] = RandomComplex[1 + I, {2, 2, 4, 16}];
W[[3]] = RandomComplex[1 + I, {2, 2, 16, 64}];
W[[n - 2]] = RandomComplex[1 + I, {2, 2, 64, 16}];
W[[n - 1]] = RandomComplex[1 + I, {2, 2, 16, 4}];
W[[n]] = RandomComplex[1 + I, {2, 2, 4, 1}];

T = RandomComplex[1 + I, {n, 2, 2, 2, 2}];
T[[1]] = RandomComplex[1 + I, {2, 2, 1, 2}];
T[[n]] = RandomComplex[1 + I, {2, 2, 2, 1}];

M = Table[0,{k,1,n},{i,1,2},{j,1,2}];

Do[
   Do[
    temp[k, i, j] = 
      Sum[KroneckerProduct[T[[k, i, l]], W[[k, l, j]]], {l, 1, 2}];
    , {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}];
   Do[
    M = temp[k, i, j];
    , {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}];
   , {k, 1, n}] // RepeatedTiming // First

Out[47]= 0.0041
```

I have **two questions**. The first is: Is there a more compact way of coding this operation than I have done? The second is: Is there a more efficient way to do this computation?

In regards to the second question, I have tried using TensorContract and Dot as some other posts suggested but I did not find any speed up. But that could be a bad implementation on my part.

Comment: Your `T` is not a tensor and hence ``Developer`PackedArrayQ[T]`` returns `False`. This might be the main reason why you don't observe any speedup. In total, neither does the $\TeX$ed formula for $M$ tell me what you try to compute (what are $a$, $b$, $\sigma$, $\sigma'$?), nor does the code that you present make any sense: _Nothing_ is computed in the end (there is no return value) and the state of $M$ after running the loops has certainly nothing to do with the $\TeX$ed formula above.

Comment: I mean would it make more sense if I put the sigma indices on the bottom? Or is that not the issue? Anyways, forget about the expression I wrote down and my code. What I am trying to do is take two 4 index tensors and contract one of the indices. Then I want to reshape my new tensor into a 4 index tensor.

Comment: i think i understand possibly what the confusion was. I have n 4 index tensors. In my formula I was writing down a contraction for a particular tensor and T[[i]] and W[[i]] and M[[i]] all refer to a particular tensor. I edited the formula to show that I am only referring to a particular i.

Comment: Are you sure that functions like `TensorContract` are not usable?

Comment: I have tried using TensorContract, but the way I was using it was something like Activate@TensorContract[Inactive[TensorProduct][T[[i]],W[[i]]],{2,5}] which didn't seem to give any speed up.